# DuplicateHandle for a file

Tags: windows, winapi

I'm trying to make DuplicateHandle() for a file that another process writes. I succeeded, but I get the position of the owner process. After I seek to the beginning it seeks also in the owner process. Can I somehow seek without changing the first process's progress?

**EDIT:**

Another application opens this file without CreateFile. Is thare a way to read the file form the begining with ReadFile, without seeking manually?

**EDIT again:**

There isn't a way to read only from one side with duplicated handle. Thanks for helping.

Comment: That seems like the expected behavior of `DuplicateHandle()`.  If the original process opens the file with the "shared read" access right, can you second application simply open the file using the normal means?  Do you have a specific reason to use `DuplicateHandle()` here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724251%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

The duplicate handle refers to the same object as the original handle. Therefore, any changes to the object are reflected through both handles. For example, if you duplicate a file handle, the current file position is always the same for both handles. For file handles to have different file positions, use the `CreateFile` function to create file handles that share access to the same file.

Comment: Can I create another handle, which refers another position. Cause I use DuplicateHandle so I can duplicate a handle of another process, so I can access the handle?

Comment: Yes. From the duplicated handle, get the filename(`GetFinalPathNameByHandle `), and pass that filename to `CreateFile` to get an independent handle.

Comment: I already know the filename, the problem is that I can't open the file with: CreateFile(filename, GENERIC_READ, FILE_SHARE_READ, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL);

Comment: @blez: Correct, `FILE_SHARE_READ` means "if anyone else has this open for writing, please don't give me the handle.  Also, don't let anyone else open new handles for writing".  Try `FILE_SHARE_WRITE`, which allows other processes to have ReadWrite handles.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of DuplicateHandle, you must call CreateFile in both process, with the right combination of access mode and sharing flag. MSDN has the [full set of rules](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363874%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), here is a combination that works :

Writer process :

```
 HANDLE file = CreateFile(..., GENERIC_READ|GENERIC_WRITE, FILE_SHARE_READ, ...);
```

Reader process :

```
 HANDLE file = CreateFile(..., GENERIC_READ, FILE_SHARE_READ|FILE_SHARE_WRITE, ...);
```

If you need to play with the flags, here is the (crude) test application I wrote to answer your question :

```
 // 2process1file.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
 //

 #include "stdafx.h"
 #include <Windows.h>
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <tchar.h>

 #define NUMBER_OF_LINES 100
 #define IO_PERIOD 250
 static const char message[] = "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.\n";

 HANDLE file = INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE;

 BOOL CtrlHandler(DWORD ctltype)
 {
     if(file != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) 
     {
         CloseHandle(file);
         file = INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE;
     }

     return FALSE;
 }

 int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
 {
     if(argc == 3) 
     {
         DWORD access = GENERIC_READ;
         DWORD share = FILE_SHARE_READ;
         bool is_writer = false;

         if((*argv[1]|' ') == 'w')
         {
             access |= GENERIC_WRITE;
             is_writer = true;
         }
         else
         {
             share |= FILE_SHARE_WRITE;
         }

         file = CreateFile(argv[2], access, share, 0, OPEN_ALWAYS, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, 0);

         if(file != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
         {
             DWORD nbytes = 1;

             SetFilePointer(file, 0, 0, FILE_BEGIN); //Redundant when writing

             for(int i=0; (i<NUMBER_OF_LINES) && nbytes; ++i) {
                 if(is_writer) {
                     if(WriteFile(file, message, sizeof(message)-1, &nbytes, 0) == 0)
                     {
                         //Write failed somehow
                         break;
                     }

                     //Sleep(INFINITE);

                     if(i%25 == 0) printf("%d\n", i); 
                 } else {
                     char buffer[sizeof message] = "";

                     if(ReadFile(file, buffer, sizeof(buffer)-1, &nbytes, 0) && nbytes) {
                         buffer[sizeof(buffer)-1] = 0;
                         printf(buffer);
                     } else {
                         //Read failed somehow
                         break;
                     }
                 }

                 Sleep(IO_PERIOD);
             }

             CloseHandle(file);
             file = INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE;
         }
     }
     else
     {
         wprintf(L"Usage : %s [w|r] filename\n");
     }

     return 0;
 }
```

Comment: The problem is that the file is read protected, while the main application is writing to it. That's why I'm making DuplicateHandle(). (alos I'm not sure about the share flags)

Comment: It's a combination of the access mode and share flags. See updated post.

Comment: With your code I get: The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.

Comment: Did you kill the process while testing it ? The file handle stays open, I did not add a break handler and such. In one cmd.exe window type 2process1file.exe w asdf.txt and in another type 2process1file.exe r asdf.txt.

Comment: Thanks for the source, too bad it couldn't help.

Comment: Yes, more so than I'm a sucker for reputation... I added a ctrl-handler so you can kill the process without locking the file. It is "works on my machine(s)" certified. Update your question with some of your code so we can help further, maybe with a Process Monitor trace ?